# How to connect low power components to high power component?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, wire, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I have a fairly standard circuit: I am controlling a 12V starter motor + 12V car battery with an Arduino PWM signal. I have an array of 4 MOSFET's to connect the low power circuit (Arduino) to the high power circuit (car battery). The low power circuit has 20AWG wire and the high power circuit has 4AWG wire, as I expect about 100A. I've never worked with anything beyond logic levels, really.

My problem is in mechanically/electrically connecting the MOSFET pins: The Drain and Source pins seem too small to connect to 4 AWG, and I couldn't solder them onto a perforated circuit board, as it cannot handle the heat generated by the current.

Is there a specific mounting component I can use to connect Gate to a low power circuit and Drain and Source to a high power circuit?

TIA!

Comment: Note: My question is not about the circuit itself, rather the connections between high and low power.

Comment: You need to make a circuit board.  Making a circuit board that can safely handle that much current is going to be quite an adventure.

Comment: You're talking about a printed circuit board? That adventure is what I'm a little worried about! I was recommended 1/2 oz copper, 16 mil trace

Comment: I'd think 2 oz is more the mark for 100A.  But like Voltage Spike said, is there a reason you don't want to use a relay?  A starter relay is designed for just this application and has 1/4" or 5/16" lugs on it which are very easy to connect 4 AWG to.

Comment: Wait a minute -- 1/2 oz copper is wimpy.  Are you actually trying to **switch** 100A?  Or just tapping straight off the battery for some lower-current things?

Comment: 2 oz., got it.
I'm connecting 5V (though I heard I might have to use 12V, totem pole driver it is), 490Hz PWM to the gate of a MOSFET array that will switch the battery-to-motor (via Drain to Source) open and closed to vary the speed of the motor with the PWM duty cycle.

Comment: The starter solenoid is not designed for PWM, though. I have it connected to the battery with a closed switch during normal operation. The motor itself is what will receive the PWM

Comment: What kind of terminal block or bus can I use to go from the motor to my PCB? I have a 14 AWG bus, but that's not enough to handle the current

Answer (score 0):

The wire (or conductor) needs to have enough cross sectional area to carry the current that the conductor is carrying. The resistance of the wire and the current will create heat, if the conductor is sized too small the wire can overheat and cause damage. The gate can have a small wire, it carries little or no current.

So the source and drain pins will need to carry 25A a piece, but you'll need to check the datasheet for the mosfet because too much current (like 25A) can burn up a mosfet if it's not rated for it, or if the mosfet is not fully off or fully on. A good thing to do would be to parallel more mosfets, as 6 mosfets would 16A a piece.

Another problem is [unbalanced mosfets](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/para.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535744b4583f79), they need to switch on and be matched somewhat or one fet can take more current and power dissipation which could cause it to burn up.

A relay would be the most robust solution and easiest to implement

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you mean that the source will carry little to no current? The source is connected to GND and the drain is connected to the Motor/Battery. That's really useful information, thank you.

I'm using IRF3205 [link](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf3205.pdf), rated for 110A at the drain, so the array is more precautionary and for power dissipation.

Comment: Oh, he said "source and drain pins" will need to carry the current.  Charge is conserved, which means that if it goes into the device somewhere, it has to come out somewhere else.  On a MOSFET that "somewhere" and "somewhere else" is the source and drain.

Comment: @NathanaelMcCooeye Welcome to the site, please read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Comment: @NathanaelMcCooeye It would be a good idea if you could get the gate to reaches 10V or more (but not more than to avoid low rdson values). Sorry for some reason I said drain but my brain meant gate

Comment: @TimWescott Sorry, I meant gate, not drain

Comment: @VoltageSpike, I was recommended 12VGS. You don't suggest anything higher than 10VGS?

Comment: @NathanaelMcCooeye "gate reaches 10V or more" I think 12v is more than 10V

Comment: I think so too :P I was confused by what you wrote in brackets.